# Image of Annulus under $f(z)=Log(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the image of the annulus $\frac 1 2 < |z| ≤ 8$ under $f(z) = Log z$

I have come across the following question type in some textbooks. I am unsure how to approach this question.

I am more concerned about understanding what the question is asking of me and what an annalus is under the principal logarithim.

I have the formal definition that: in the complex plane the annulus is an open region defined as

$r<|z-a|<R$

If $r$ is $0$, the region is known as the punctured disk of radius $R$ around the point $a$.

If anyone could try to break down this concept for me or even provide examples that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$, with $r\in (\frac12,8]$ and $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ for the principal argument. Then,

$$w = \log(z) = \log(re^{i\theta})=\ln r + i\theta$$

Thus, the image represents a rectangular region in the complex plane, i.e. $Re(w)\in(-\ln2,\ln8]$ and $Im(w)=(-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: The set of $w\in\mathbb{C}$ you specify indeed satisfies $e^{w}=z$ with $|z|$ as desired. However, for any such $w$, also $w'=w+2\pi k i$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies that equation. Please see my post below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\text{Log}(z)=\ln r+i\theta$$where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Hence the circles $r=\text{constant}$ are mapped to $$(x,y)=(\ln r,\theta)\quad,\quad -\pi<\theta\le \pi$$which draw vertical line segments placed at $x=\ln r$.

Answer (score 1):

$Log(z) = \ln|z| + iArg(z)$, here $Arg(z)$ is the principal argument which takes values in $(-\pi, \pi]$. So, it maps any full circle $|z|=r>0$ to vertical half open line segment of length $2\pi$ centered at $\ln(r)$. That is, with abusing some notation, maps to $\ln(r) \times (-\pi, \pi]$. Now if you consider your annulus as consisting of circles whose radii changes from $1/2$ (which is not included) to $8$, you will get those vertical lines starting from $x=\ln(1/2)$ (which is not included) to $x = \ln 8$. Hence you will get a rectangle in my abused form: $(\ln(1/2), \ln 8] \times (-\pi, \pi] $. That is, a rectangle such that leftmost edge and the bottom edge is not included.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=|z|e^{i \phi}$, we have $\log z= \log \left( |z|e^{i \phi}e^{2\pi i k}\right)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ because $e^{2\pi i k}=1$.

Thus
$$\log z= \log |z| +i \phi + 2\pi i k $$ and if $\frac{1}{2}<|z|\leq 8$. Thus for $k=0$, the image of the annulus is the rectangle of $w\in\mathbb{C}$ such that its real parts satisfy $\Re(w)\in(-\log 2,\log 8]$ and imaginary parts $\Im(w)=\phi\in[0,2\pi)$. Each (arbitrary) integer $k\neq 0$ adds  a rectangle where $\Re(w)\in(-\log 2,\log 8]$ and imaginary parts $\Im(w)\in[k2\pi,(k+1)2\pi)$, shifted in parallel to the imaginary axis.

As all integer $k$ are possible, the full image of the annulus asked for is the stripe 
\begin{equation}
  S=\{w\in\mathbb{C} \ | \ \Re(w)\in(-\log 2,\log 8] \wedge \Im(w)\in \mathbb{R} \} 
\end{equation}
parallel to the imaginary axis.